# R scripts load automatically

Tags: r

I have gotten an old package from CRAN that contains some R scripts, the question that I have is how I can load those scripts automatically without the need to open and run them line by line, is there any way possible?
The package was called knnflex and it was deprecated from CRAN. There is a zip available for R for windows in:

http://cran.uvigo.es/web/packages/knnflex/index.html

but when one installs the package, it occurs a problem with the namespace, due to lack of compatibility (I dont put the problem or the solution here, because it was solved before in a thread in SO). I have included the namespace in the zip file with a trick that I found in this page, but some functions like predict are not recognized at all.

One turnaround that I make it was to download the tar.gz file, uncompress it and inside the R folder there are the scripts that make it possible to work. So actually I am loading those scripts one by one and then make it run separately line by line and it works.

So that is why I was asking if there is a way to call those scripts automatically.

Long story, but I think it can be helpful to other people also.
Thanks

Comment: You haven't provided many details here. Are you aware that you can automatically run R code on startup via your `.RProfile` file in your working directory?

Comment: Are you familiar with `?source` (as in `source("path/to/example/exampleScript.R")`)?

Comment: I mean what I need is to or to put those R scripts in a package or to load automatically just calling their name as calling any function

Comment: Which old package, and what scripts, and what functions?

Comment: knnflex, inside the tar.gz file there are scripts in R; by the way I have donwloaded the zip version, but it does not work well with the latest version of R. Also, when I make the tweak to fix the namespace problem it still does not work at all. For all those reasons I am using the original R scripts

Comment: Do you mean the package source files? Because those really aren't "R scripts", in the usual sense. This is really still far too vague, so I'm voting to close.

Comment: "it occurs a problem with the namespace" - Can you understand how this is still a woefully incomplete description of your problem?

Comment: The problem with the namespace is because the lack of compatibility with the new version of R and this old package. I dont put the solution with the namespace here, because is in this forum. I think that I have put the question clearly, that is how I can make a script to run automatically. I just dont know what other type of explanation is needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't cleaned it up much but I moved those source files into my github repo so if you have the devtools package installed you can install knnflex with the following commands...

```
library(devtools)
install_github("knnflex", "Dasonk")
```

But really if you just want to load Rscripts then `source` is what you should be using.

If you want something to run when you load R then you should put it in your .Rprofile file.  You can learn more in `?Startup`